# For loop reading empty variable

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, string

I have a subroutine that runs in my batch file, during which I output to a textfile the success of each operation. An example is this...

```
set Tasks=One Two Three
set LogFile=Log.txt

for %%T in (%Tasks%) do call :Operation %%T

:Operation
set LogEntry=%1
echo %LogEntry%>> %LogFile%
goto :EOF
```

Using this I can get one, two and three written into the text file but I also get a final entry with an empty variable.

Can anyone see what the issue is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:operation` is just a label. When the `for` command ends its work, the batch file continues its execution, enters the code after the label and the code inside it gets executed, but this time without any passed parameter.

Place a `goto :eof` or a `exit /b` after the `for` command to avoid it

```
set Tasks=One Two Three
set LogFile=Log.txt

for %%T in (%Tasks%) do call :Operation %%T
goto :eof    

:Operation
set LogEntry=%1
echo %LogEntry%>> %LogFile%
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Great help! Very well observed and noted by myself! Thanks :)